# Codeigniter rest server enable keys for login process

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter

I am using chriskacerguis Rest Server as my backend processor and have recently enabled

```
$config['rest_enable_keys'] = TRUE;
```

I created the required table and managed to generate api keys for each user. However, I discovered that I can only use this when a user is already logged in. If they are not, the server returns

```
{"status":false,"error":"Invalid API key "}
```

Is there a way to decide when this is activated and default to a standard username password authentication for logging in only?

Comment: Right now the only way I can see this working out with a key is if I separate the login function onto a separate application without this keys enabled. However, I'd like to avoid that if possible.